# GNOME 3 - Fedora Where can I find administrative items?

Tags: fedora, gnome3

I recently migrated to FEDORA 15 (Devpt. Release) from Ubuntu, the I am unable to locate the items like firewall, services in the GUI offered. I am not keen on modifying through the configurations through the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be in one of these places:

- Activities -> Applications -> Other
- Activities -> Applications -> System Tools

May also want to try the search box when you trigger Activities. You can do this by putting your mouse cursor in the upper-right hand corner of the screen, and just type `firewall<enter>`.